# To get api data based on the id

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

**Scenario:**

I have an api :

`https://................../api/branches`

As in the api `/branches` means the api as multiple `branches` with unique `ID` .Each `branch` will have it's own `contacts`.

Now i am calling one particular branch `contacts` **by mentioning the particular branch ID(i,e 8f00752-cdc6)** like this:

**customers.services.ts file**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IBranch, IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class CustomersService {
 private  baseUrl : string = 'https://................../api/';
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

 public getBranchesInfo(branchId : string): Promise<IBranch> {
  const apiUrl: string = 'https://................../api/branches/';
  return this.http.get<IBranch>(apiUrl + branchId).toPromise();
 }

  public async getContactList(branchId: string): Promise<IContact[]> <=======
  {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}branches/${'8f00752-cdc6'}/contacts`;
    return this.http.get<IContact[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }

}
```

And to disaply the **contacts** i am calling **getContactList** method in another component called `contacts` like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  IContact } from 'src/app/models/app.models';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'asw-contacts',
  templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
})
export class ContactsComponent  {
  public contacts: IContact[];

  constructor(public customersService: CustomersService) {} 

  public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.contacts = await this.customersService.getContactList('');
    console.log(this.contacts);
  }


}
```

Here i can **log** and see the **contacts** of that mentioned **branch(i,e 8f00752-cdc6)**

> **Requirement:** Instead of hard coding **branch ID(i,e 8f00752-cdc6)** in **customers.services.ts file** and getting only that mentioned branch(i,e 8f00752-cdc6) **contacts**, I want get `contacts` of `branch` based on **which branch i selected from the dropdown**

For this i have another component called **branch** where i am calling all the `branches` and displaying in the **dropdown** like this :

[image]

**branch** component code:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Branch">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branches" [value]="branch.id">
      {{branch.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomersService } from 'src/app/services/customers.service';
import { IBranch } from 'src/app/models/app.models';

@Component({
  selector: 'asw-branch',
  templateUrl: './branch.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./branch.component.css']
})
export class BranchComponent implements OnInit {
 public branches: IBranch[];

  constructor(public customersService: CustomersService) {} 

 public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.branches = await this.customersService.getBranchesInfo('');
  }

}
```

How can i pass the **branch id** after selecting from the `dropdown` present in **branch** component to the method i,e:

```
public async getContactList(branchId: string): Promise<IContact[]>{
   const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}branches/${'id'}/contacts`;<=======
        return this.http.get<IContact[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
 }
```

in `customers-services.ts` file?

Answer (score 2):

try somehting like this:

put (onSelectionChange) event on your mat option

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Branch">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branches" [value]="branch.id"  (onSelectionChange)="selected($event, branch.id)">
      {{branch.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

then in your component ts:

```
async selected(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, id: string) {
    if (event.source.selected && id) {
      console.log(id);
      this.result= await this._productService.getContactList(id);
    }
  }
```

and in your service.ts

```
  public async getContactList(businessId : string): Promise<IContact[]>{
       const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}branches/${businessId}/contacts`;<=======
            return this.http.get<IContact[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
     }
```

Hope this help you!!

Comment: Getting this error: **"message":"Http failure response for https://............../api/branches//contacts: 400 OK","error":{"id":["The value 'contacts' is not valid."]}}**

Comment: In the `debugger` i saw i am getting the clicked `branch id` upto `services` file but i  am unable to get that idt in `contacts` component.

Comment: i think your BACK END ANEDPOINT URL is bad configured .. can you post it?

Comment: URL is fine i can see the all values in **POSTMAN**, The clicked `branch id` from the list is coming upto `services` file but not to the `contacts` component, I am missing something.

Comment: but sorry you contact compoent is in OTHER component where is located the mat-option ???

Comment: `mat-option` is located in an component calle `navbar`. From clicking the dropdown from `navbar` i am injecting the branch id to the function `getContactList` in `services` file. Then i am calling  the function `getContactList`  in `contacts` component